# Rest Assured - shows bad request

Tags: post, rest-assured

**Here It's my request xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Request>
    <user>
        <title>Mr</title>
        <firstname>automation</firstname>
        <lastname>Qa</lastname>
        <department>Automation</department>
        <mobile>999000777</mobile>
    </user>
</Request>
```

**Here it's my actual Rest Assured Code :**

```
String APIUrl = "http://autoTest.com/api/1/user/create";

        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        hashMap.put("title", "Mr");
        hashMap.put("firstname", "automation");
        hashMap.put("lastname", "testing");
        hashMap.put("department", "test");
        hashMap.put("mobile", "7878787");

        Response response = RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive() .basic("userName", "passw0rd"). 
parameters(hashMap).when().post(APIUrl);
```

**When i do this call it's give me Following kind of Error in console :**

```
Bad request ,
Request resource or xml is not valid ,
Sorry, we could not find appropriate method or xml.
```

Can anyone help me to find what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `contentType("application/xml")` so that rest assured knows that it should serialize the map as XML.